# How to get the values in this object?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get the values from the below object without any luck. I know there are many answers out there, but I am a visual person and they are not working for my layout.

Also, how can I address the objects to change the values of "ringAlarm"?

```
var strRingAlarm = {
    sq1 :{ringAlarm:"OFF", alarmName:"Chime1"},
    sq2 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime2"},
    sq3 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime3"},
    sq4 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime4"},
    sq5 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime5"},
    sq6 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime6"},
    sq7 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime7"},
    sq8 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime8"},
    sq9 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime9"},
    sq10:{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime10"},
    sq11:{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime11"},
    sq12:{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime11"}
};
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(strRingAlarm).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
        console.log(val + ' -> ' + val.ringAlarm);
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ringAlarmProperty like this

```
 for(var prop in strRingAlarm){
   console.log(strRingAlarm[prop].ringAlarm)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var strRingAlarm = {
    sq1: {ringAlarm:"OFF", alarmName:"Chime1"},
    sq2: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime2"},
    sq3: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime3"},
    sq4: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime4"},
    sq5: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime5"},
    sq6: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime6"},
    sq7: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime7"},
    sq8: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime8"},
    sq9: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime9"},
    sq10: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime10"},
    sq11: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime11"},
    sq12: {ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime11"}
};


Object.getOwnPropertyNames(strRingAlarm).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
    console.log(val + ' -> ' + strRingAlarm[val].ringAlarm) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var strRingAlarm = {
    sq1 :{ringAlarm:"OFF", alarmName:"Chime1"},
    sq2 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime2"},
    sq3 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime3"},
    sq4 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime4"},
    sq5 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime5"},
    sq6 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime6"},
    sq7 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime7"},
    sq8 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime8"},
    sq9 :{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime9"},
    sq10:{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime10"},
    sq11:{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime11"},
    sq12:{ringAlarm:"NO", alarmName:"Chime11"}
};


for(key in strRingAlarm){
  console.log(key + "..." +strRingAlarm[key]['ringAlarm'])
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why `ringAlarm` is in `['ringAlarm']` as opposed to `.ringAlarm`?

Comment: Thank you all, so very much, this was kicking my azz!!

Comment: we can use any one of them, i just typed early...that's it

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `name` of a property of an object `obj`, the best way to get the value of that property is `obj[name]`. In this way, try this code block:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(strRingAlarm).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
  console.log(val + ' -> ' + strRingAlarm[val].ringAlarm);
});
```